# Endless /error on 404 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a file missing, in my case "images/html5.png",

when i load the page it keeps getting loading for some reason
pulled firebug and this is what i get:

```
GET /error 302 Found
GET /error 302 Found
GET /error 302 Found
GET /error 302 Found
GET /error 302 Found
.......
```

It should give me a 404 (not found)
instead it keeps loading /error and after 20 retries it gives up

Comment: Could you please give us more info about your code, what this image is, where it's loaded?

Comment: Ill try to add as much info as i can:

Comment: Ill try to add as much info as i can. Its CI with smarty, and with mod_rewrite. If i try to load an image, ex: localhost/application/theme/admin/images/logo.png2 (does not exist) it loads the page, but keeps loading, however it trows a 302 found error on the logo.png2, and keeps loading the page localhost/cms/error, after 10+ trys it gives up and the pages stops loading. Screenshot: [link]http://postimg.org/image/52iufiprv/

Comment: Found this in the .htaccess file: ErrorDocument 404 /error, removed it, still the same